# What to install to enable to run RESIDENT EVIL Revelations 2 on my windows 7 pc?

Tags: system-requirements, resident-evil-revelations-2

These are my pc specs.

```
OS: Windows 7 64-bit
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 3.00GHz
RAM: 6gb
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 440
```

I already installed the updated directx, .NET FRAMEWORK and Microsoft Visuals C++, I don't know what to do next.

First it kept saying that I don't have MSVCP100.dll or something like this, I then downloaded this and put it in system32 folder, then the next problem it kept saying that the application cant start because of the 0xc000007b error message. I did all what online suggestions said like,

- uninstall then reinstall the app/game I want to run
- reinstall the softwares needed to run this game
- recopy or replace the ddl files of system32 to syswow64 folder
- use chkdsk/f command
- check for any windows update
- restart my computer
- stop my antivirus to avoid corruption of the app and so on.

I still get the error message 0xc000007b. But it said in any pc requirements can I run it website; I can run the game but only minimum requirements not the recommended but still I can play the game it said, I don't know what to do guys, I don'twant to give up this game cause I already downloaded it.

[image: My PC SPECS]

[image: My PC Specs]

Comment: How are you installing the game?

Comment: *"I already installed the updated ... Microsoft Visuals C++"* have you downloaded and installed both 32-bit and 64-bit versions? from my research the 0xc000007b error is being caused by missing the 32-bit .dlls

Comment: *"I then downloaded [MSVCP100.dll] and put it in system32 folder"* i hope where ever you download the .dll from is safe and trusted because for something like MSVCP100.dll you shouldn't be downloading the .dll itself from a website, you should be using Microsoft's installers downloaded from their site

Comment: MSVC distributables are among the many things Steam should install for you as part of a game's dependencies. If it doesn't, you should probably ask Steam Support for help.

Comment: Which "Microsoft Visuals C++" stuff did you install? `MSVCP100.dll` is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (the 100 actually stands for 10.0, which is 2010's internal version).  Since the game is likely 32-bit, you'd need the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)" distribution.

Answer (score -1):

your pc specs seems fine. that error you mentioned happened to me many times... unfortunately there is no specific solution for that. every pc has their own problems/solutions...

but since you have 64bit operating system, try to replace 64 bit dll files instead of 32bit ones.

also you may want to check those steps there(i strongly suggest you to check comments as well)
https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-the-application-is-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc00007b-error/